# Negotiation for trial contract pay?

Tags: negotiation, contracting

I'm currently on a trial run contract (hourly) for a division of a company I'm interested in working with in the future. They've asked me to do some work, for which if I were just a contractor would usually charge at least in the $35-55/hour range, depending on the work. However, due to previous relationships with other parts of the company I am already on payroll, officially being paid hourly at $15/hour.

I've been asked to quote an hourly rate for this contract work for them. It's pretty small - probably 8 hours max of work - and at the end of the day I'm willing to do it at the 15/hour rate I'm currently getting, because the opportunity for future full-time work is far more valuable than the extra few hundred dollars right now. Even if it doesn't pan out, the risk-reward analysis in my mind still is okay with doing this work for 15/hour. The full-time position is not definite yet by any means, but there does appear to be significant interest on all parts. Finally, one of my mentors works in this division so I do have a personal relationship already - I wouldn't be doing this with strangers.

That said, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I am willing to be underpaid for this because I'm here to prove my competence, but at the same time I don't want to be undervalued or seem low-value/unprofessional - things that would be relevant during the negotiation phase if a full offer is extended.

How should I proceed? Should I ask for a higher rate, say that my current hourly is fine, maybe go the other direction and offer to do it for free?

EDIT:

To add some more clarification, the complex part of this is that the full-time position is not yet formalized, nor offered. This contract is something they happen to need right now anyway, and if I were to work for them is part of the work I might do, and so it's partially one-shot contract and partially trial run.

They know they will hire someone and are strongly considering me -- to the point that they joked about writing the job listing so I would be the only qualified applicant. On a more serious note, I've essentially already had a first interview with them before they've even posted. I've also been given a probable pay range for if this does go through, which is pretty good.

Finally, I currently hold a full-time job, but they're trying to recruit me away so I feel like trying to undervalue me during negotiations later on will not be a productive strategy for them - I can turn them down without fear.

Comment: What happens if they aren't willing to pay you when the contract is complete?

Comment: @Brian The is not about will he get paid when the contract is complete.

Comment: @Blam Understood. I'm trying to focus on the "opportunity for future full-time work" part of it. If the OP is willing to work for free or cheap now, the organization could try to take advantage of him later.

Answer (score 2):

*Usually* the right negotiation strategy when asked to quote your value would be to pick the top of the range. That would be $55.

Be ready to back up with comps (comparisons) from the industry. It sounds like your floor here should be $35 - far improved over the $15 you are proposing - but they shouldn't know that, i.e. your comps should be $40+ and if they dig up a $35 one, so be it.

Note that one scummy but effective hiring technique is to take you on for low pay for a "trial basis." If you accept this you already lost all your leverage and can expect a raise to $20 or something like that. Therefore, I do believe you read the situation right:

> That said, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I am willing to be underpaid for this because I'm here to prove my competence, but at the same time I don't want to be undervalued or seem low-value/unprofessional - things that would be relevant during the negotiation phase if a full offer is extended.

Yes, what you are paid right now reveals exactly what you would take during the "negotiation phase." By the way, you're already in the negotiation phase. *You have your greatest leverage right now.* Don't squander it.

Answer (score 0):

It would almost have been better if they had not asked you to quote a rate. Ideally you would show value before you negotiate a rate.  I don't agree with djechlin that you have your greatest leverage right now.  My thought is go in with you current rate but cap it at like 8 or 20 hours.  If they like your work you have a better change of getting closer to that $55.  If you go in now at like $35 to get the work then you are locked in.

Comment: I can't help but feel that this OP will have tremendous difficulty getting anything extra in the future, perhaps even as much as $20per. Regardless of previous work or contracts, if you are not under contract to do the type of work they are now looking for - pick your hoped for pay and stick to it. Anything different when/if the contract is picked up simply won't happen. OTOH, if you are/were under contract already for the exact same type of work, it'd be unlikely they will accept such a bump now.

Comment: Why would I pay you $55 when I already know you're willing to work for $15? In particular I know that you weren't able or willing to find another opportunity paying you more than $15.

Comment: @djechlin Because I got the opportunity to prove I was worth $55.  So you don't agree - you have an answer.  They already know he will work for $15 / hour as he is now.  They have acknowledged the new work is going to be more.  Really 8 hours at $15 / hr locks him in forever - I don't agree.  An 8 hour commitment does not prove he cannot find another opportunity.

Comment: The answer to the question is simply that if real contractors charge 35-55, then why aren't you? They'll have to pay 35-55 to get the work done from someone else, except there's you, who aren't confident that you're worth 35-55 but are confident you're worth 15. If you're different from 35-55 contractors before the 8 hours why are you suddenly the same 8 hours later? You prove that you are willing to work for 15 in this situation because you aren't being the contractor who would charge 35-55. The employer won't randomly triple your pay because you "did well."

Comment: Rather they will explain why your work "could be better" and pay you 15 regardless of how well you do. Sorry. The world is not that kind.

Comment: @djechlin Maybe that is how you negotiate but not me.  If someone agrees to work at low rate for short period of time to demonstrate their worth I will negotiate in good faith at the end of that term.   I feel like I have always done better at negotiating a rate after people have seen my work and the other party has negotiated in good faith.  I am sorry if your world is not that kind.  You have an answer.  We don't agree.  That does not mean I am absolutely wrong.  Let it go